# Is it OK for SEO to remove old WordPress image uploads that are no longer being used on the site?

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect, 410-gone

If I'm re-building a website that is not going to be using older image uploads, what's best practice in terms of SEO? Do I just delete the old uploads and move on or is it better to 301 them to the replacement image/most relevant image/page?

Maybe 410 Gone makes more sense?

PS; I will be removing date categorization as well.

> `www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/oldimagename.jpg`

> `www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/newimagename.jpg`

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend on whether you want these still to be indexed?

Comment: @RohitGupta I'd want the old images to eventually not exist and not be indexed.

Comment: Then I would go for 401, but you do have to remove references to them on other pages (or mark them as nofollow)

Comment: @RohitGupta Got it. And yes, all instances of the old images are going to be removed completely. Thank you!

Comment: Are you worried about Google image search rankings, or just about the main web rankings for the site?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Mostly image search. Would like the older images to eventually be deemed irrelevant by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Removing images that are no longer being used on your website should normally not be a problem. The only cases that I would not delete them are:

1. If they are being used by Google (if Google is relating these images to your website or your brand) or
2. If these images are bein used as backlinks from other web pages